# Link Github to Namecheap: Validation failed

Tags: github, dns

I am trying to link my Github account to my Namecheap account so I can use a custom domain for my Github page, but when I try to login this happens:

[image: Validation Failed]

A few notes that might be handy:

- I use 2 factor authentication on GH
- I tried using my regular password but it told me to use my 2FA OTP code
- I generated a personal token on GH and used that instead of my password to login (which produced the error)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: got the same error and no idea how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chatted with the helpdesk and he said that you have to create the cname record pointing to your github account manually.

http://davidensinger.com/2013/03/setting-the-dns-for-github-pages-on-namecheap/